# create span tag and add in particular div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid row template in my MVC project where i have one `div`.
Below is my sample code:

```html
<script id="altRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
  <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="#: uid #">
    <td style="width:100%">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="dvCategory"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

I am appending `span` in `div` using jQuery.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
  if (data.data[i].Category != null) {
    var splitCategory = data.data[i].Category;
    var setCategorySpan = "<span class='tags' style='font-family: arial; font-size: small'>" + splitCategory + "</span>";
    $("#dvCategory").html(setCategorySpan);
  }
}
```

But `span` tag with value not showing in `div`.
I tried with append also but no luck.

Now the current code is like below:

```js
    function changeTemplate(category) {
            var splitCategory = category;
            var setCategorySpan = '';
            if (splitCategory.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
                splitCategory = category.split(',');
                for (var i = 0; i < splitCategory.length; i++) {
                    var setcolID = 2;
                    // Trim the excess whitespace.
                    splitCategory[i] = splitCategory[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
                    // Add additional code here, such as:
                    setCategorySpan += "<div class='col-sm-" + setcolID + "'><span class='tags' style='font-family:arial; font-size:small'>" + splitCategory[i] + "</span></div>";
                    setcolID+=2;                  
                }
                $("#dvCategory").append(setCategorySpan);
            }
            else {

                setCategorySpan = "<div class='col-sm-12'><span class='tags' style='font-family:arial; font-size:small'>" + splitCategory + "</span></div>";
                $("#dvCategory").append(setCategorySpan);
            }
        }
```

```html
   <script id="altRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="#: uid #">
        <td style="width:100%">
          <div id="Category">    
              #:changeTemplate(Category)#                                             
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </script>
```

and in `document.ready` function i have created `div` where i have to append HTML.

```js
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('id', 'dvCategory');
container.setAttribute('class', 'row');
```

if i am `using $('body').append(container);`
then all the value is showing out of grid body.
if i am removing the code then nothing is showing.
How do i append dynamically created html in this specific `div` category?

Comment: You're overwriting the `html()` of `#dvCategory` in each iteration of the loop, so only the last `span` will be shown. However if you're getting no output at all it sounds like you may have an error in your code - check the console

Comment: But currently not a single span display here.

Comment: unfortunetly there is no error in console.

Comment: did you tried some console.log on data.data[i].Category and $("#dvCategory").size() ?

Comment: I think your problem is just a question of time... have you tried using **on document ready** to start your js script?

Comment: Hi Arhak, I think you are right when grid is binding so that time this div is not created i checked size of grid which is null after append html. I have done some changes in my code that i am editing now with my current question.

Comment: print the conten with console.log() to check the output of your vars... and update the question with this info.

Answer (score 3):

This example demonstrates a way to find **when** an element has been added in the document. After that you can append anything you want.

```js
/* A small function that appends the html you want in the desired div and returns true*/
function addMoreToCategory() {
  if ($('#dvCategory').length > 0) {
      $("#dvCategory").append("<br><span class=\"extra\">and this is added when this element is visible</span>");
      /* fade in extra content and fire alert callback on finish */
      $(".extra").fadeIn(1200,function() {
        alert("finished loading extra content");
      });
      return true;
  }
}

alert("dvCategory not in Document");

$("#clickThis").on("click",function(){
   $(".row").html("<div id=\"dvCategory\">Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>");
   alert("dvCategory added in Document");
});
/* add an interval of 1 second to loop */
var v1 = setInterval(function() {if(addMoreToCategory()===true) {
  /* once content is added once then stop */
    clearInterval(v1); 
}}, 1000);
```

```css
.extra { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

</div>
<button id="clickThis" type="button">
Click
</button>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40edzhbx/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to bind out side the for loop. Without using to much append inside loop create markup using += as a string and finally append html in div.

```
var data={};
data.data=[{Category:1},{Category:2},{Category:3},{Category:4}];
var setCategorySpan = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
  if (data.data[i].Category != null) {
    var splitCategory = data.data[i].Category;
    setCategorySpan += "<span class='tags' style='font-family: arial; font-size: small'>" + splitCategory + "</span>";

  }
}
$("#dvCategory").html(setCategorySpan);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data={};
data.data=[{Category:1},{Category:2},{Category:3},{Category:4}];
console.log(data.data[1]);
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
  if (data.data[i].Category != null) {
    var splitCategory = data.data[i].Category;
    var setCategorySpan = "<span class='tags' style='font-family: arial; font-size: small'>" + splitCategory + "</span>";
    $("#dvCategory").append(setCategorySpan);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!script id="altRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
  <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="#: uid #">
    <td style="width:100%">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="dvCategory"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing this simple code:

```
   $("#dvCategory").html(''); 
   for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {

    if (data.data[i].Category != null) {

      var splitCategory = data.data[i].Category;

      var setCategorySpan = "<span class='tags' style='font-family: arial; font-size: small'>" + splitCategory + "</span>";

      $("#dvCategory").append(setCategorySpan);

     }

   }
```